# setting variables to false

Tags: apache-flex

I am working in flex and I am just setting a variable to false. It doesnt do anything in the program but everything breaks when I put this line of code in:

somevar = false;

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please be more specific.  What do you mean, `everything breaks`?

Comment: I think the reason is because I add it to my onLoad method. but why?

Comment: Post some snippets of code and the output you're seeing.  Is the code still compiling?  Are you seeing a runtime error?

Comment: need more to go on...what breaks? Are you getting a run-time exception or is it just not doing what you expected? If it's not too big, can you post your onLoad method code and also any run-time error stack output you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is somevar declared as a Boolean?

```
var somevar:Boolean;
```